# CSS not working / loading on Codepen react pen

Tags: css, reactjs, codepen

My pen: https://codepen.io/thelastvampire/pen/GzbqNQ.
`please visit the pen above`
I'm following a tutorial called "30 days of react"(https://github.com/fullstackreact/30-days-of-react). I want to do this on codepen, starting with the day-04 as my skeleton. But the css just doesn't work. I inspect the elements and I don't see the css. But when I run the project (day-04 only from the repository) on my computer, I can see that the same css works and loads well. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a reason why code is mandated for questions linking to external sites: you need to reproduce the code in a minimal, verifiable, and concrete way **within the question itself**. Simply formatting a random string of text with code is bypassing the requirement and does not improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checked your code, issue was that you have not added demo class in your root div element.
check your code after adding this in your html file

```
<div id="app" class="demo"></div>
```